# Lefschetz numbers for homomorphisms of free groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, free-groups

Let $G = F_X$ be the free group on a finite set $X$, and $\phi\colon G\to G$ a group homomorphism.  Consider the number

$$ \sum_{x\in X} (\text{number of occurrences of the generator $x$ in the word $\phi(x)$}) $$

where occurrences of $x^{-1}$ are counted negatively.  Does this number bear any significance in group theory?  Note that if $\phi$ is the identity map, the formula above reduces to the rank of $G$.

*Background*: a finitely generated free group $G$ has a classifying space $B G$ which is Spanier-Whitehead dualizable, hence the endomorphism $B \phi\colon B G \to B G$ has a Lefschetz number.  The formula above computes $1 - L(B \phi)$.

Comment: This number bears no significance in group theory. 

Comment: If I remember correctly, the following paper uses the Lefschetz fixed point theorem to decompose the homology representations of groups of finite automorphisms of surface groups into irreducibles: http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3002 .  The same idea would work for free groups.

Answer (score 8):

Isn't this the trace of the endomorphism induced by phi on the abelianization of G, which is the free abelian group over X?

Comment: Yes.  Does that help answer the question of whether it bears any significance in group theory?